# C++:Am i correct to define the body for a private function and public function?

Tags: c++

in BST.h file I have:

```
class node
{
public:
node* left;
node* right;
int key;
}
class BST
{
public:
void add(int newKey);
private:
node* root;
node* addHelper(node* nd, int newKey);
};
```

I then implement add and addHelper function in bst.cpp file:

```
 #include "BST.h"

    public void add(int newKey){

       addHelper(root,newKey); 

    }

   node* BST :: addHelper(Node* nd, int newKey)
   {
       //do something..

   }
```

Do I still need to define my `public add(int newKey)` function as: 
`void BST :: add(int newKey)` in bst.cpp?

Comment: Yes. Right now, you're declaring `BST::add`, but defining `::add`.

Comment: Besides what Jerry Coffin said, `public` has no place there. It is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you need to specify that you are defining the function `add` which is a member of `BST`, as opposed to a free function named `add`.

In the following example, the two functions are separate, even though they have the same name:

```
void add(int newKey)
{
   // Code to define free function named `add`
   // - this function is not a member of any class
}

void BST::add(int newKey)
{
   // Code to define function named `add` which is member of class `BST`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` function should be defined as :

```
void BST::add(int newKey){

   addHelper(root,newKey); 

}
```

The access specifier is only required in the class definition. And the scope resolution operator is needed here to tel that this is the same `add()` the belongs to `BST`.